# Angular upgrade and jquery issue

Tags: jquery, angular

As part of angular 6 to 15 migration, I have to update jquery as well. earlier we have used

```
"@types/jquery": "2.0.33" 
"jquery": "3.1.1"
```

As part of package.json, since we have upgraded to angular, we have jquery as below:

```
"jquery": "^3.6.4",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.16"
```

In one of the places we have used the below query function in the .ts file

```
this.cssService.setElHeight($('.div .content h4'));
```

Below is the service method:

```
setElHeight(element: any) {
        element.height('auto');
        if (element.length) {
            let maxheight: number = 0;
            element.each(() => {
             
              let max_height = $(this).height() ?? 0; //here I get error  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultView')
              maxheight = (max_height > maxheight ? max_height : maxheight);
            });
            element.height(maxheight);
        }
    }
```

at line " `let max_height = $(this).height() ?? 0;`" we get error as below:

```
" Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultView')"
```

Instead of `$(this)` I tried `$(element)`, but some of the content don't get proper height.

Comment: jQuery probably expects `this` to be the window object, which would provide `window.document.defaultView`, so if `this` is, instead, your service class instance due to ES6 arrow functions, you might need to explicitly reference `window` in `let max_height = $(window).height()`. (Although, ideally, you should use an injection token to inject `window` instead of using it directly.)

Comment: actually, I want the height of the element where the stated method "setElHeight" is applied

Answer (score 1):

Avoid directly manipulating the DOM using jQuery or any other external library. Angular provides its own way of interacting with the DOM using ElementRef and Renderer2.

Import ElementRef and Renderer2 from @angular/core:

```
import { ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

Inject ElementRef and Renderer2 into your service's constructor:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
```

Modify your setElHeight method to use Renderer2 instead of jQuery:

```
setElHeight(element: ElementRef) {
  const el = element.nativeElement;
  this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'height', 'auto');
  if (el.length) {
    let maxheight: number = 0;
    element.forEach((el: any) => {
      const max_height = el.offsetHeight || 0;
      maxheight = (max_height > maxheight ? max_height : maxheight);
    });
    this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'height', maxheight + 'px');
  }
}
```

Update your template to pass the ElementRef to the setElHeight method

```
<div #content class="div content">
  <h4>Some Content</h4>
</div>
```

hope it's work perfectly

**`Using JQuery`**

```
setElHeight(element: any) { 
  element.height('auto');   
  if (element.length) { 
    let maxheight: number = 0;  
    element.each(function() {   
      const max_height = $(this).height() || 0; 
      maxheight = (max_height > maxheight ? max_height : maxheight);    
    }); 
    element.height(maxheight);  
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nikhil Makwana, I know this works and this would be a great approach when it is an angular way but my scenario is that this is an old application, changing the approach would take time and lots of testing, therefore I would appreciate if you provide an approach in a jquery way.

Comment: @DevDeveloper i Understood i've added jquery example in my answer please check

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this error on "this", "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)"

Comment: @DevDeveloper remove my old code and i'hv updated new code please check

Comment: I think we are rounding back, you bring back to my original question

Comment: @DevDeveloper you've any demo or stackblitz  link?

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working following way: it might be useful to someone who is in same need:

```
 setElHeight(element: any) {
        element.height('auto');
        var $elem = $(element)
        if ($elem.length) {
            let maxheight: number = 0;
            $elem.each(function(key, value)  {
                const max_height = $(this).height() || 0; 
                maxheight = (max_height > maxheight ? max_height : maxheight);
            });
            element.height(maxheight);
        }
    }
```